# End User License Certificate for APK File in Android?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have published my app in android market successfully. I have signed my app by Eclipse IDE. that is Exporting the Android Application and setting alias name and credentials like that.

Now i want to upgrade my app. i have changed my version code and version name in the manifest file. Now i have to sign my application with the same certificate(i.e. selecting same alias name) to publish the update else it will throw error like certificate does not match.

So My doubt is about if i changed my PC then i can copy all of my workspace to that machine. But how can i get the same End User Certificate to that machine.

Is there any possible way to get it. Any Idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you tell me in which directory you have create you previous apk?

Comment: You would have signed the app using a key(~/keytool/abc.keystore), either through eclipse or command line, that key will be saved in your home folder in linux. so you just need to have your key with you and if package name of the project is same, you can sign it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you create apk it will also genrate certificate insame directory now with using it you can update you apk.

if there are not problem of sdk then take precaution mention in following step ::

**1. your package name is match with previos package

 2. your minSDK version are not change in manifest file

 3. must use previos certificate with password confidentiality.

 4. change version code as well as version name**